# WILDFLY - Loading jar dynamically java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, classpath, wildfly

I have an EAR deployed in wildfly and I'm loading a jar from source with this code:

```
File file = new File("C:\\XXXX\\XXXX\\ProcessTest.jar");   
String lcStr = "com.package.test.TestProcess";      
URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{file.toURL()});

Class<?> loadedClass;
try {
    loadedClass = cl.loadClass(lcStr);
    IProcess data = (IProcess)loadedClass.newInstance();
    data.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The TestProcess class implements IProcess that is loaded in another jar with the EAR.

When I run the server code and the class is being casted I receive:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/package/test/process/IProcess

---

If I added the interface in the JAR that I'm loading the problem is a CastException because com/package/test/process/IProcess loaded by wildfly is different of the loaded with the JAR.

I need receive the IProcess (casting the object), because a solution is call directly the method with Mehtod.invoke but it's not solution for my problem.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Try `URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{file.toURL()}, IProcess.class.getClassLoader())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this tip works perfectly:

URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{file.toURL()}, IProcess.class.getClassLoader())

Thanks to Steve C!